# Optimizing a distinction code

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
List<int> types = new List<int>();
foreach (var d in myTableList)
{
    if (!types.Contains((int)d.item_type))
        types.Add((int)d.item_type);
}
```

I have a table in db called myTable. There is a column in it called item_type. It is integer.

I want to make a list which would have all item_type which are in myTableList, but there shouldn't be duplicates.

I tried:

```
types = myTableList.Distinct(x => x.item_type)
```

but I want types to be list of integers, not items of type myTable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
types = myTableList
    .Select(x => (int)x.item_type)
    .Distinct();
```

You may also want to add `.ToList()` at the end if you want to match original code

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just use a `HashSet<T>` to do the distinction for you:

```
var types = new HashSet<int>(myTableList.Select(x => (int)x.item_type)).ToList();
```

Comment: `Distinct` does exactly that

Comment: Just to expand my previous comment... Distinct uses `HashSet` to ensure uniqueness of elements, and  outputs element if it has not been seen before.

Comment: Yes, hence why I said "another option".